# Problems YouTube download

Tags: youtube

Did install SMPlayer and the SM Youtube browser in Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS however, the server cannot be found. What can be the problem please?

Comment: IS there any error message? can you provide any additional information ..=)

Answer (score 2):

Try the package `youtube-dl` from the universe repository.

```
sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
```

Normal procedure to run it is:

```
youtube-dl <youtubeurl>
```

e.g.

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okqEVeNqBhc
```

Youtube-dl can download from a huge number of different video sites. Complete list:

```
1tv
1up.com
220.ro
24video
3sat
4tube
56.com
5min
8tracks
9gag
abc.net.au
Abc7News
AcademicEarth:Course
AddAnime
AdobeTV
AdultSwim
Aftenposten
Aftonbladet
AirMozilla
AlJazeera
Allocine
AlphaPorno
anitube.se
AnySex
Aparat
AppleDailyAnimationNews
AppleDailyRealtimeNews
AppleTrailers
archive.org
ARD
ARD:mediathek
arte.tv
arte.tv:+7
arte.tv:concert
arte.tv:creative
arte.tv:ddc
arte.tv:embed
arte.tv:future
AtresPlayer
ATTTechChannel
audiomack
audiomack:album
Azubu
bambuser
bambuser:channel
Bandcamp
Bandcamp:album
bbc.co.uk
Beeg
BehindKink
Bet
Bild
BiliBili
blinkx
blip.tv:user
BlipTV
Bloomberg
Bpb
BR
Break
Brightcove
BuzzFeed
BYUtv
Camdemy
CamdemyFolder
Canal13cl
canalc2.tv
Canalplus
CBS
CBSNews
CBSSports
CeskaTelevize
channel9
Chilloutzone
chirbit
chirbit:profile
Cinchcast
Cinemassacre
clipfish
cliphunter
Clipsyndicate
Cloudy
Clubic
cmt.com
CNET
CNN
CNNArticle
CNNBlogs
CollegeHumor
CollegeRama
ComCarCoff
ComedyCentral
ComedyCentralShows
CommonMistakes
CondeNast
Cracked
Criterion
Crunchyroll
crunchyroll:playlist
CSpan
CtsNews
culturebox.francetvinfo.fr
dailymotion
dailymotion:playlist
dailymotion:user
daum.net
DBTV
DctpTv
DeezerPlaylist
defense.gouv.fr
Discovery
divxstage
Dotsub
DRBonanza
Dropbox
DrTuber
DRTV
Dump
dvtv
EbaumsWorld
EchoMsk
eHow
Einthusan
eitb.tv
EllenTV
EllenTV:clips
ElPais
Embedly
EMPFlix
Engadget
Eporner
EroProfile
Escapist
EveryonesMixtape
exfm
ExpoTV
ExtremeTube
facebook
faz.net
fc2
fernsehkritik.tv
fernsehkritik.tv:postecke
Firedrive
Firstpost
Flickr
Folketinget
Foxgay
FoxNews
france2.fr:generation-quoi
FranceCulture
FranceInter
francetv
francetvinfo.fr
Freesound
freespeech.org
FreeVideo
FunnyOrDie
Gamekings
GameOne
gameone:playlist
GameSpot
GameStar
Gametrailers
GDCVault
generic
GiantBomb
Giga
Glide
Globo
GodTube
GoldenMoustache
Golem
GorillaVid
Goshgay
Grooveshark
Groupon
Hark
HearThisAt
Heise
HellPorno
Helsinki
HentaiStigma
HistoricFilms
History
hitbox
hitbox:live
HornBunny
HostingBulk
HotNewHipHop
Howcast
HowStuffWorks
HuffPost
Hypem
Iconosquare
ign.com
imdb
imdb:list
Imgur
Ina
InfoQ
Instagram
instagram:user
InternetVideoArchive
IPrima
ivi
ivi:compilation
Izlesene
JadoreCettePub
JeuxVideo
Jove
jpopsuki.tv
Jukebox
Kaltura
Kankan
Karaoketv
keek
KeezMovies
KhanAcademy
KickStarter
kontrtube
KrasView
Ku6
la7.tv
Laola1Tv
Letv
LetvPlaylist
LetvTv
lifenews
LiveLeak
livestream
livestream:original
livestream:shortener
LnkGo
lrt.lt
lynda
lynda:course
m6
macgamestore
mailru
Malemotion
MDR
media.ccc.de
metacafe
Metacritic
Mgoon
Minhateca
MinistryGrid
mitele.es
mixcloud
MLB
MoeVideo
Mofosex
Mojvideo
Moniker
mooshare
Morningstar
Motherless
Motorsport
MovieClips
Moviezine
movshare
MPORA
MTV
mtviggy.com
mtvservices:embedded
MuenchenTV
MusicPlayOn
MusicVault
muzu.tv
MySpace
MySpace:album
MySpass
myvideo
MyVidster
n-tv.de
NationalGeographic
Naver
NBA
NBC
NBCNews
ndr
NDTV
NerdCubedFeed
Nerdist
Netzkino
Newgrounds
Newstube
NextMedia
NextMediaActionNews
nfb
nfl.com
nhl.com
nhl.com:news
nhl.com:videocenter
niconico
NiconicoPlaylist
Noco
Normalboots
NosVideo
novamov
Nowness
nowvideo
npo.nl
npo.nl:live
npo.nl:radio
npo.nl:radio:fragment
NRK
NRKTV
ntv.ru
Nuvid
NYTimes
ocw.mit.edu
Odnoklassniki
OktoberfestTV
on.aol.com
Ooyala
OpenFilm
orf:fm4
orf:oe1
orf:tvthek
parliamentlive.tv
Patreon
PBS
Phoenix
Photobucket
PlanetaPlay
play.fm
played.to
Playvid
plus.google
pluzz.francetv.fr
podomatic
PornHd
PornHub
PornHubPlaylist
Pornotube
PornoXO
PromptFile
prosiebensat1
Puls4
Pyvideo
QuickVid
R7
radio.de
radiobremen
radiofrance
Rai
RBMARadio
RedTube
Restudy
ReverbNation
RingTV
RottenTomatoes
Roxwel
RTBF
Rte
rtl.nl
RTL2
RTLnow
RTP
RTS
rtve.es:alacarta
rtve.es:live
RUHD
rutube
rutube:channel
rutube:embed
rutube:movie
rutube:person
RUTV
Sandia
Sapo
savefrom.net
SBS
SciVee
screen.yahoo:search
Screencast
ScreencastOMatic
ScreenwaveMedia
ServingSys
Sexu
SexyKarma
Shared
ShareSix
Sina
Slideshare
Slutload
smotri
smotri:broadcast
smotri:community
smotri:user
Snotr
Sockshare
Sohu
soundcloud
soundcloud:playlist
soundcloud:set
soundcloud:user
soundgasm
soundgasm:profile
southpark.cc.com
southpark.de
Space
Spankwire
Spiegel
Spiegel:Article
Spiegeltv
Spike
Sport5
SportBox
SportDeutschland
SRMediathek
stanfordoc
Steam
streamcloud.eu
StreamCZ
StreetVoice
SunPorno
SVTPlay
SWRMediathek
Syfy
SztvHu
Tagesschau
Tapely
Tass
teachertube
teachertube:user:collection
TeachingChannel
Teamcoco
TeamFour
TechTalks
techtv.mit.edu
TED
tegenlicht.vpro.nl
TeleBruxelles
telecinco.es
TeleMB
TeleTask
TenPlay
TestTube
TestURL
TF1
TheOnion
ThePlatform
TheSixtyOne
ThisAV
THVideo
THVideoPlaylist
tinypic
tlc.com
tlc.de
TMZ
TNAFlix
tou.tv
Toypics
ToypicsUser
TrailerAddict (CURRENTLY BROKEN)
Trilulilu
TruTube
Tube8
Tudou
Tumblr
TuneIn
Turbo
Tutv
tv.dfb.de
TV4
tvigle
tvp.pl
tvp.pl:Series
TVPlay
Tweakers
twitch:bookmarks
twitch:chapter
twitch:past_broadcasts
twitch:profile
twitch:stream
twitch:video
twitch:vod
Ubu
udemy
udemy:course
UnicodeBOM
Unistra
Urort
ustream
ustream:channel
Vbox7
VeeHD
Veoh
Vesti
Vevo
VGTV
vh1.com
Vice
Viddler
video.google:search
video.mit.edu
VideoBam
VideoDetective
videofy.me
videolectures.net
VideoMega
VideoPremium
VideoTt
videoweed
Vidme
Vidzi
vier
vier:videos
viki
vimeo
vimeo:album
vimeo:channel
vimeo:group
vimeo:likes
vimeo:review
vimeo:user
vimeo:watchlater
Vimple
Vine
vine:user
vk.com
vk.com:user-videos
Vodlocker
Vporn
VRT
vube
VuClip
vulture.com
Walla
WashingtonPost
wat.tv
WayOfTheMaster
WDR
wdr:mobile
WDRMaus
WebOfStories
Weibo
Wimp
Wistia
WorldStarHipHop
wrzuta.pl
WSJ
XBef
XboxClips
XHamster
XMinus
XNXX
XTube
XTubeUser
Xuite
XVideos
XXXYMovies
Yahoo
Yam
YesJapan
Ynet
YouJizz
Youku
YouPorn
YourUpload
youtube
youtube:channel
youtube:favorites
youtube:history
youtube:playlist
youtube:recommended
youtube:search
youtube:search:date
youtube:search_url
youtube:show
youtube:subscriptions
youtube:truncated_id
youtube:truncated_url
youtube:user
youtube:watch_later
Zapiks
ZDF
ZDFChannel
zingmp3:album
zingmp3:song
```